# google app engine using python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am a really beginner of google app engine and trying to figure out how to create a link to the other pages. Like after the user sign in, I want that there is link button that can redirect the users to some other pages I created .Thank you so much

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn a bit about [HTML links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) first

Answer (score 2):

Do you already understand how to create pages?  If so, then linking between pages is just basic HTML:

```
<a href="/path/to/some/page">link text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a link to the other pages in Google app engine using python:
For example: hyperlink: `<a href="/addproduct">` where `/addproduct` refer to the name of the class in .py file, Here is how the `addproduct` class is defined in .py file

```
class addproduct(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('adminaddproduct.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())
```

Answer (score 0):

[Redirect](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/redirects.html) is easy:

```
self.redirect("/home")
```

[Example app](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers.html)  also shows how users are redirected to the app after signing in.

Comment: For future reference and to improve the quality of my answers, maybe someone can explain what is so bad with this answer that it needed to be downvoted? The question asks about how redirect users after they sign in.